# How to access each element in an array Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

```
my@arr=qw(Larrywall);
```

This is my array, but i want access only `Y`. How to do this please let me know. Good answers will be appreciable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about `hello world` type of question

Comment: That's a single-element array; the element is the string `"Larrywall". In Perl, strings are scalars, not arrays. And there's no `Y` character in the string (though there is a `y`). I suggest you update your question so it's clearer about just what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

`qw(Foo Bar)` is the same as `('Foo', 'Bar')`.

with `my @arr = qw(Larrywall)` you create an array with one element. If you would like to iterate through every character of your string, you have to split it into characters:

```
my @arr = split //, "LarryWall";
```

The `//` part is the regex on which you want to split your string. In this case we use the empty pattern which always matches, so it will essentially split on every character.

If you have an array and you want to split each element into its characters, you could do something like this:

```
my @arr = map { split //, $_ } qw(Larry Wall SomethingElse);
#=> qw(L a r r y W a l l S o m e t h i n g E l s e)
```

or

```
my @arr = map { [split //, $_] } qw(Larry Wall SomethingElse);
#=> ([qw(L a r r y)], [qw(W a l l)], [qw(S o m e t h i n g E l s e)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) on the array's only element:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = qw(Larrywall);
print substr $arr[0], 4, 1;
```

Output:

```
y
```